# When loading a config file, is it possible to not include by default the Java Properties in the returned Config instance?

Tags: java, scala, typesafe-config

Running

```java
var config = ConfigFactory.parseFile("app.conf")
```

will include both the settings I've defined in that file and all the settings one can get through `System.getProperties()`.

I was wondering if it was possible to somehow load *only* the settings defined in my file, as I may, later on, want to make some changes and print out a slightly modified version, which is now polluted with all these extraneous settings.

Comment: Have you tried `java.util.Properties#load`?

Comment: I don't understand your comment, @daniu. TypesafeConfig is including the properties by default. I don't want them there.

Comment: Are you sure you used `parseFile`? It shouldn't resolve anything at all, as opposed to `load`. And with `load` you could `ConfigFactory.load("app.conf", ConfigParseOptions.default(), ConfigResolveOptions.noSystem())`.

Comment: Do you have any includes in this file? Are those that brought up to your `config`? I can't reproduce your claim.

Comment: Hi. I've tried changing it to `Config config = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf", ConfigParseOptions.defaults(), ConfigResolveOptions.noSystem());`, but it will still load the application's properties.

Comment: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/9N6kyKjeRFWSMUzL0zdtmw/2

Comment: You seem to be into something. But unfortunately, I will need to load things from files / resources. The `ConfigResolveOptions.noSystem()` seems to have no effect?

Comment: `parseFile` acts the same as `parseString`. They should not add the environment variables. Only `load` does. Can you create [mcve]?

Comment: What do you do with the `Config`? Are you passing it into something that could perform resolution?

Comment: @TomerShetah: That's correct. The problem is, I will want to load this .conf file as a resource. Maybe I should manually get its contents as a string and then use `ConfigFactory.parseString()`, then..

Comment: What do you mean by "load this .conf file as a resource"? You can do `parseFile` with the file path and get what you want

Comment: The file is inside a jar.